# Ubuntu 16.04.1 - converting an ext4 filesystem from MBR to GPT?

Tags: 16.04, mbr, gpt

What's the up-to-date/simplest method of using gdisk to convert an ext4 drive from MBR to GPT? 
I have seen many different older methods described but I don't know which one is relevant for the modern versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: I do not think it has changed. Converting to or from GPT
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html But why are you converting? And you do have to add either a bios_grub or ESP partition and reinstall grub. Often better to just totally re-partition & reformat drive, reinstall Ubuntu and restore /home, installed apps from exported list and any other data you backup.

Comment: Converting for better resilience and error-reporting when the disk starts to go wrong. I had a drive on MBR recently that went kaput and I found out later there might have been a chance to recover data if it was on MBR. Anyway I'm going to try and run sgdisk or gdisk after backing everything up. I'll report back. If it doesn't work, then all I have is the most recent updates on Ubuntu.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, the bootloader was ruined by the gdisk operation. I don't know what the right way is, but one of the wrong ways is to just run gdisk on the drive without any other kind of setup.

Comment: As mentioned above, with gpt you have to have a bios_grub partition (1 or 2MB unformatted with bios_grub flag or if gdisk code ef02) if using BIOS to boot or an ESP if using UEFI to boot (300 to 500MB FAT32 with boot flag or with gdisk code ef00). I typically add both as first two partitions on every drive & larger flash drives. Only then will reinstalling grub work.

Comment: As noted by oldfred and described on the page he referenced, converting from MBR to GPT will require re-installing your (or installing a new) boot loader. This isn't a question of the procedure being "older" or "wrong"; it's simply required by the type of conversion you're attempting. In your specific case, the aphorism "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" applies. Your configuration wasn't broke, but you insisted on fixing it. You must now fix your fix, by repairing your boot loader setup. The best way to do that depends on details you've not mentioned, like whether your computer supports EFI.

Comment: @RodSmith re: "if it ain't broke.." I mentioned this in a comment "I had a drive on MBR recently that went kaput and I found out later there might have been a chance to recover data if it was on MBR. "

Comment: Yes, but the change you made was far riskier than the risk of an MBR failing in a way that a GPT would not. GPT is superior to MBR in many ways, but that does not make MBR a broken technology.